# Will I ever need to use ejs or layouts if I use Angular for frontend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I'm currently using Sails for backend, which comes with an ejs view engine and a templating system which is rather neat. However, setting up Angular on the front end of things will get in the way of these functions.

For instance, I can no longer use templates, because if I have say `<html ng-app="myApp">` inside `layout.ejs` Angular will never initialize.

Same thing should I include any ejs templates.

So what I have done now is created a `index.html` file inside my `assets` folder, turned off the Sails routes and layouts, and am purely working with Angular. This will do fine for my current project (except I can't make things as tidy as I'm used to, the boilerplate html need to sit there, etc.) but will it be a problem in other projects, I wonder?

In other words, what am I missing out on by not using ejs? How will I ever be able to get things from my Sails controllers into my views? Or won't I need to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First this question is WIDE open to interpretation based on all sorts of variables.

If your using your APP simply as JSON delivering API, then in reality you don't need to use the template engine. So the basic premise of your question is valid.

However, their are still plenty of reaons to use the template engine.

For instance, you can still use EJS to setup your default layout and index page for your angular site.

> For instance, I can no longer use templates, because if I have say  inside layout.ejs Angular will never initialize.

This statement is completely wrong. I use server render templatse for my index page on a SPA in order to use my app version to point to updated assets and template files. That way old template files will not be cached when I update my app. Depending on the app the index page may be the only one to use the template engine as everything else will use static templates. Others I have the server render my templates using the template engine as well (for example: if I want to restrict certain aspects of my templates based on a user role.)

There are other reasons as well. You might try the Google Groups for sails as this is more of an open ended question.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sailsjs

Comment: Oh thank you. Well, the statement itself isn't wrong because I did test it, but I get what you're saying in that there's a way to set up things so that it will work. May I ask how that structure looks like, loosely? What do I need to do to get Angular to work if I "initialize" it in a layout file?

Comment: It depends on your setup. If you want use a server generated index page for your spa, then you first need to create a top level policy that will check if the request wants json. If it does not, then you need to redirect to index.html. This assumes the only html page you have will be the index. Otherwise you setup your layout / index page the same way documented on the sails site for plugging scripts and css. You can also create your own grunt / gulp tasks to render ng-templates as well. Like I said, long question / answer. Try google groups if you want more robust answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Angular for frontend and SailsJs for the backend the best practice is to have two distinct applications which means you don't have use sails to render the views (No EJS mandatory ).
AFAIK SailsJS just need to be used as a REST API while Angular needs to render your views ( you could use http.post get put and delete to comunicate with your api).

Best Regards.

Comment: This is not the best practice. It is A practice. In fact NG-Europe the double click teamed talked about a method of modifying your templates on the server before sending them to the client.

Comment: Obviously you can use template processing with angular/ejs or whatecer with sails, but if he want to optimize response time he should use sails as a REST API. 
The method you are talking about is just what's named template processing and as far as i know it take more time to rendering a view and send it than send json output and load with angular just the part of your dom you need to update. 
If popular people or a group of people talk about a practice this is not always a best practice, take it like a recommended usage.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

As sails.js is purely backend and Angular.js is purely frontend, they can work together nicely.

All you need to do is place your angular files and logic in

> myapp/assets

folder. Assets folder is by default acessible on sails server url.

You can access it as http://localhost:1337/assets/file_name.

As for the ejs, if you are using any javascript framework like angular.js then it is not a requirement as all JSON api will be made in sails framework and angular will get data in JSON format.